# Hide other data-targets or div different then the current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with hiding the other `div`s when the target one is active, so, my jQuery is:

```
$(".popup-itens").click(function () {
    var selector = "#" + $(this).data("target");

    $(selector).toggle();
    console.log(selector);
});
```

I just simply want to hide all the other `data-targets` `div`s that are different from `$(this)`.

I've tried if statement and other stuff, but nothing seems to really work.

Comment: difficult to give a proper answer without seeing your markup, you should add it to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could negate the current element (`this`) using the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.popup-itens').not(this).hide();
```

Therefore it would look something like this:

```
$(".popup-itens").click(function () {
    var selector = "#" + $(this).data("target");
    $(selector).toggle();
    $('.popup-itens').not(this).hide();
});
```

Alternatively, depending on the markup, you could also select all the elements with `data-target` attributes using an attribute selector, then negate the current selector:

```
$('[data-target]').not(selector).hide();
```